# Why react router's BrowserRouter does not fill native window.location properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router's `BrowserRouter` for appliying routing in my react app.

However, I realized that when the URL changes, that change is not reflected in `window.location`.

For example when my app is loaded, the `window.location.search` is empty. When I click on tickets menu to go to `example.com/tickets` the `window.location.search` is still empty.

Is there a configuration to force react-router to fill `window.location` properties?

Comment: You can always listen for route changes and update the window object yourself, but you probably should avoid touching the window object in React. What is the use case?

Comment: We are creating an SPL, software product line. We want to be able to deliver our own API to our developers. A developer working on our products should get a URL query as simple as `import app from 'app'` and then `const { ticketId } = app.query()`. That's the use case. And I thought what's a better way than using the well structured `URLSearchParams` from JavaScript and use `window.location`.

Comment: Then why use `react-router` and, presumably, `react-router-dom` and not sip the location from the routing context? Pass `location.search` to a `URLSearchParams` constructor. If using RRDv5 see [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) for working with query parameters. If using RRDv6 it's even easier, they export a [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook for you.

Comment: I wish they did not mess with defaults in the browser. JavaScript is much easier to work with than react's rules of hooks. I couldn't make it work with react-router. We're using react-router-dom, but we're stuck.

Comment: Well, I don't know about Javascript, as a whole, being "easier than React's rules of hooks" as the hook rules are pretty simple and very cut and dry. Like I said though, using a custom history object you can listen for route changes and update/maintain any "state" you like. FWIW I just did a quick test in a codesandbox, logging out `window.location` after some route changes and I see the correct updates reflected in `window.location` in both RRDv5 and v6.